# What is the difference between 'Included Features' and 'Dependencies'?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi, eclipse-rcp

When defining an OSGi/ Eclipse RCP feature, I can define Included Plug-ins, Included Features and Dependencies.

I would like to know what is really the difference between these things and what exactly will the Eclipse RCP Runtime do with these different information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'Include Plug-ins' are plugins that are part of this feature. They will included in the RCP build.

'Included Features' are other features that will be included in the RCP build when you include this feature. It is quite common to have a feature for each component of a large RCP (like Eclipse) with a top level feature including the component features.

'Dependencies' are other plugins and features that you are saying your feature depends on. This is mainly for features which you export as 'deployable features' rather than an RCP build. The feature install will check that the dependencies are already installed when installing this feature.

Comment: Would it make sence to always define my dependencies in all my features, particularly all the org.eclipse.* core functionality?
And what happens, if two features 'include' the same other feature? I guess they will not be added twice?

Comment: "Would it make [...]" -- yes all dependencies should be there if you are doing "deployable features". The idea is that feature.xml has all the dependencies so that after someone installs your feature it works with no extra work, the installer will have ensured all dependent features are installed. That said if you are creating a standalone RCP application and not making p2 sites to install in third-parties eclipse installs, you may not bother to worry about dependencies.

Comment: And why would I define any depencendies in the feature if all the plug-ins, that are included in the feature and it's included features, already define their dependencies?
So, why do I need feature dependencies if i can (and should) already define all dependencies in the plugin?

Comment: You put your plugins and features in the feature includes. You put plugins and features that you already expect to be installed (such as core Eclipse) in the feature dependencies. The RCP builder doesn't look at the dependencies in the plugin manifest.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to greg-449's answer:

> what exactly will the Eclipse ECP Runtime do with these different information?

The runtime won't do anything really with the feature contents, unless you are installing/updating features. The feature.xml are a build/install/update "thing" that describes inclusions and dependencies.

Said in another way, if you create a standalone product, you don't need to have any feature.xmls for your product to work ok. In the .product file, list included plug-ins (after setting *The product configuration is based on* to *plug-ins* in the Overview tab)